# Regular Expression in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are using Neo4j Database using Spring Data Neo4j . Now we have a lot  of cypher query in which we use Regular Expression , right now we are in development mode so we have only 2000 nodes in our database , Does it affects the performance if Neo4j Database have millions of node ???? 
Is there any way to get rid out from it ?
Or we have to make such type of cypher in which we have no regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j won't use indexes for regular expressions, so that would definitely affect your query performance as you grow.

Could you some examples of regular expressions?  There might be a be another way to go about it.

Depending on your regular expressions, you might be able to duplicate the functionality with legacy indexes.  Alternatively you could use an external tools like [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) to support full-text searching

Comment: yeah , Actually lets suppose there is search box in which user type eve, then now we have to find %eve% , And much more than it like , there are many Node Labels like Event, User,Job etc . So it found from every Label . We also think about of using elastic search . But in elastic search there is problem of indexing in which we schedule , we want an instantious result like a Job is created then it will be shown within a minute

Answer (score 1):

In one of the next versions, Neo4j will support indexes for LIKE operations. Probably not for regexp expressions.

You can use the manual lucene fulltext index for such queries, just annotate your field with

@Index(type=FULLTEXT, indexName="search") String description;

And then you can use the query syntax in the `START` clause.

See here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-start.html#_get_node_or_relationship_from_index

```
START n=node:search("description:keyword")
RETURN n
```

See also: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/